# Make SQL value equal a PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql

i have trouble making MySQL Source value equal $source:
`$result = mysql_query("SELECT Source FROM videos
WHERE Name='$name'");
$source=['Source'];`

Comment: `mysql_query` is deprecated at not to be used in new code. Please look up [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: It appears that you haven't made any effort at all, as any one of a *million* tutorials will tell you the correct syntax for this, up to and including the official docs provided by PHP. Please learn to help yourself, rather than posting such utterly trivial questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Source FROM videos WHERE Name='$name'"); 
$ds = mysql_fetch_object($result);
$source= $ds -> Source;
```

This would do it, but you should use mysqli

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT Source FROM videos WHERE Name = '$name'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$your_var = $row['Source'];
```